# MySQL before Trigger, set multiple fields using query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, triggers

I'm trying to execute trigger on before insert of table.

Table structure :-

service :- id, name.

clinic :- id, company_id, name, service_id.

user :- id, clinic_id, company_id, service_id.

```
CREATE TRIGGER user_before_insert_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON `user` FOR EACH ROW
      BEGIN                            
         SET NEW.service_id= (select CL.service_id from clinic as CL where CL.id=NEW.clinic_id LIMIT 1);    

         SET NEW.company_id= (select CL.company_id from clinic as CL where CL.id=NEW.clinic_id LIMIT 1);         
     END
```

I need to set `service_id` and `company_id` on insert using trigger.

I had executed separate queries to get `service_id` and `company_id` from `clinic` table. That need to convert in a single query.

Please give some suggestions to improve the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to declare local variable and assign value into select query [Mysql Select Into](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html)

```
CREATE TRIGGER user_before_insert_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON `user` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE service_id integer; 
    DECLARE company_id integer; 
    SELECT CL.service_id,CL.company_id into service_id,company_id from clinic as CL where CL.id=NEW.clinic_id LIMIT 1
    SET NEW.service_id= service_id;
    SET NEW.company_id= company_id;         
END
```